# Ito process that is a submartingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Could anyone give me an example of an Ito process that is submartingale? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $B_t^2$, with $B$ a Brownian motion.

More generally, for an Ito process like $X_t=X_0+\int_0^t H_s\,ds+\int_0^t K_s\,dB_s$, if $H_s\ge 0$ a.s. for all $s$, then $X$ is a submartingale.

Comment: I was thinking about the square of a Brownian Motion too. Thank you